# How can I fix "the referenced script on this Behaviour is missing" warnings?

Tags: unity

One of my game objects used to have a script that I have now deleted on purpose. Now it keeps saying this message as a warning:

> The referenced script on this Behaviour is missing!

How can I rid of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the missing reference from your GameObject. You attached your script to something, remove the now missing component, and done.

Comment: It also happens when you rename the file and the Class somehow, that's why I actually asked. I did copy the content of the script anyway, then removed the file, and finally remaking all over again. Oh, and pasted the code of course.

Comment: Renaming in Unity works actually, outside probably not.

Comment: @Fabián That is because the class name and file name no longer matchup. If you change the class name to match it should work

Answer (score 0):

Another potential reason why this error might occur is that your script *file name* and script *class name* are different. **For example:**

**`Incorrect Setup`**

[image]

[image]

**`Correct Setup`**

[image]

[image]